# 'help.vim' syntax file, example string to match 'helpHeadline' element

Tags: regex, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am playing with vim syntax files and using help.vim as a guide to create my own syntax file.  Changes I make in my syntax file are correctly applied in a test file but my problem is with creating a string to match `helpHeadline`; it's definition is:

`syn match helpHeadline     "^[-A-Z .][-A-Z0-9 .()]*[ \t]\+\*"me=e-1`

Can anyone give me an example string that would match it please.

Comment: It would match something like `-FOO *"me=e-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @hwnd helped me to find the answer myself.

An example string would be:

```
ABC *
```

Note the text at the end of the regular expression `me=e-1` is not part of the regular expression but is a vim script statement used in syntax files.